# Writing Stories. Haram or not?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, books, poetry

I've heard and read proofs that writing fictional stories are haram. Some people, like me, are given talents of writing poems and stories and the like. I've made up a story that is really beneficial and I've always dreamed of sharing this with people, but the main character was born with strange powers (growing claws and teleporting, i.e. moving from place to place in a second.) The story goes on about how he is trying to live despite the people who are chasing after him to end him. Is it haram if I write something like this? If it is haram, can I make him inherit the power by one of his ancestors who was injected by an undiscovered drug?

Answer (score 0):

If the story has/promotes anything that Islam already forbids, it is Haram. Otherwise nothing is wrong with it, the Prophet and the companions used to listen to poetry which contained so often storytelling, [Banat Su'ad](https://scholarship.haverford.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1136&context=religion_facpubs), Ka'b ibn Zuhayr's poem of praising the prophet is an example of that, it starts with a fictional inception.

That's to say, if storytelling were haram it would be very obvious since it was a common thing of the environment in which the Prophet and his companions lived.

Also another example of storytelling in the Islamic world is [Kalila and Demna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kal%C4%ABla_wa-Dimna), which was famously translated/edited by [Ibn al-Muqaffa'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Muqaffa%27).

Answer (score 0):

Asalam Alikum
You can write stories as long as there are no bad things/haram like  wine,beer,s@x,I would recommend not drawing characters or living things as that is imitation of the creation of الله.So even your story has to abide by islamic law.

Answer (score -1):

If storytelling is not about forbidden things, there is no problem